# I need to create a delay for text2 in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As the title suggests. You can see in my code, I have text and text2 that forms the text for the typing effect. But they both start at the same time. I would like to create a delay on text2 so that it starts when text finishes. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text:"This is sample text",
      text2:"This is sample text for text2",
      count:0,
      show:"",
      show2:"",
    }
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.update(),
      300
    );
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  
  update(){
    const counter = this.state.count;
    const letter = this.state.text.charAt(counter);
    const letter2 = this.state.text2.charAt(counter);
    const textlength = this.state.text.length;
    //let text += letter;
    console.log("counter : " + counter + " / letter : " + letter);
    console.log("counter : " + counter + " / letter2 : " + letter2);
    
    if(counter <= textlength){
    this.setState({
      show: this.state.show + letter,
      show2: this.state.show2 + letter2,
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
    }else{
      clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hello Wayne did you not appreciate [my first answer to this exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66283759/9078341)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i create a second line with a delay in this typing effect function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283612/how-do-i-create-a-second-line-with-a-delay-in-this-typing-effect-function)

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn , Thank you for your assistance. I do appreciate it. I did try following your list of things to do. But its still not working out for me. I think i may be misunderstanding something. As Im still learning and my understanding in general is not that great. Is it at all possible to explain it to me like Im 5 years old? As you can see i did manage to get the second line going. Im not sure if it's the right way of doing it. But it's going never the less. Its just this delay thing that is getting to me now.

Comment: It wasn't the exact same question though. Last time it was mainly about the second line of text. Now it was mainly about a delay to that text. So in fact it is a similar question. But i get what you are saying. Thank you for the assistance you have given me. I will delete my other post and try my luck else where.

Comment: And I quote from the other question: "_How would i create a second line with a delay so that it starts after the first line._"

Comment: Ok understood @RandyCasburn, I'll try do thing's a little better in the future. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
update() {
  const counter = this.state.count;
  const text1 = this.state.text;
  const text2 = this.state.text2;
  const letter = text1.charAt(counter);
  // Note: It'll be empty string for negative index
  const letter2 = text2.charAt(counter - text1.length);
  const textlength = text1.length + text2.length;

  if(counter < textlength) {
    this.setState({
      show: this.state.show + letter,
      show2: this.state.show2 + letter2,
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  } else {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
}
```